# Set div tag height, on condition

Tags: html, css

I have div tag, I want make so: if content div tag is low than 100px, set div tag height exactly 100px. but if content height is higher than 100px - set div tag height automatically,  please tell me css for this.

Comment: use `min-height:100px` for the div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply following style..

```
 style='min-height:100px;'
```

Answer (score 1):

cross

```
min-height: 100px; 
height:auto !important; 
height: 100px;
```